# FileNotFound Exception while converting Firebase uri into bitmap?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i'm developing an app in which i'm retrieving a profile image from firebase but while conversion into bitmap format ,it's getting `FileNotFoundException` so any solution for this ?

```
databaseReference.child(uid).child("Profile_image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String url= (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

         Uri uri;
             try {
                 uri = Uri.parse(url);
                 InputStream inputStream =getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);   //this line
                 Bitmap bitamp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                 String bitmap=saveToInternalStorage(bitamp);
                 loadImageFromStorage(bitmap);

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for replying i'm getting uri properly to firebase ,so issue is in inputStream to bitmap in picasso its working fine..

Comment: Have you tried to use [Picasso library for android](http://square.github.io/picasso/)?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes but firstly i want to store it into internal memory for this i want to change it into bitmap that's the issue.

Comment: What is value of your `my_uri`?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's http url of Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to use Picasso direcltly
Picasso.get().load(uri).into(target);

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to be a comment, but I don't have a high enough reputation to comment yet:

If your `String url` is the http url of Firebase storage, then `Uri.parse(url)` is not going to get you the correct Uri. From my experience, you can only be confident that `Uri.parse(String stringUri)` will return the correct Uri if the string came from Uri's `toString()` method.

Receiving an invalid Uri would cause `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` crash as you say it is.

With that being said, if you're storing the Uri as a String in your database, then you need to get that String value and use `Uri.parse(String stringUri)` on it as opposed to calling that method on the http url.